# hello i have some problems with this perl -wne'while

Tags: regex, perl

I have some problems with this

```
perl -wne 'while(/(?:(?:\b00|+)08[. ]?)?3\d{2}[. ]?\d{6,7}\b/){print "$&\n"}' *.txt >save
cat save |sort|uniq>mmm
wc -l mmm
```

How can I exatrct from a file some phone numbers .. the numbers start with 08 ..

Comment: What problems do you have?

Comment: don`t wotk .. the phone numbers don`t extract

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input and the expected numbers to extract? Note that `|+` fails for me with `Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/|+ <-- HERE / at ...`.

Comment: (31, 'cell', 20, '', '0860720877', 0),
(41, 'cell', 25, '', '0879057884', 0),
(43, 'cell', 26, '', '0879565724', 0),
(46, 'cell', 28, '', '0872374089', 0),
(23, 'cell', 15, 'Terri', '0872213090', 0),
like this looks

Comment: Your regular expression has a `3`, as if you expect each phone number to begin with `083...`.

Comment: @MyUnivers: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53216837/edit) to include the input data that you have given in a comment. Unformatted data in a comment is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: `+` is a metacharacter you need to escape or else you will see the error message

> `Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?:(?:\b00|+ <-- HERE`

So change the expression in that group to `(?:\b00|\+)`

Problem 2: `while (condition) { ... }` is an infinite loop if `condition` is true and if `condition` doesn't change inside the loop.

When the script does find a match, the while loop will never terminate and it will print out the first match it finds into the file `save`, forever.

An alternative to `while (/.../) { print $& }` that will Do What You Mean is `for (/.../g) { print $_ }`. The `/g` modifier asks Perl to find as many matches as it can on the input. The `for (LIST) { ... }` construct loads each element of the list into the topic variable `$_`.

Updated script now looks like:

```
for(/(?:(?:\b00|\+)08[. ]?)?3\d{2}[. ]?\d{6,7}\b/g) { print "$_\n" }
```

If you continue to have trouble, include examples of your input, what you expect the output to be, and any error messages you observe when your code runs.

Comment: ie]# perl -wne'for(/(?:(?:\b00|\+)08[. ]?)?3\d{2}[. ]?\d{6,7}\b/g) { print "$_\n" } *.txt >save;cat save |sort|uniq>mmm;wc -l mmm
> ^C  don`t work ..

Comment: What does the `3` mean?  `08[,]?)?   --> 3 <--- \d{2}[.] ...`

Comment: sorry i copy it from other comm and i foggot to delete it